# Color of a nitrogen oxide atmosphere

Tags: planets, atmosphere, chemistry

I've got [a planet with a very special atmosphere](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/43918/nitrogen-oxide-atmosphere). The properties are as follows:

- Surface pressure = 0.7 atm
- Composition:

  - 60% NO
  - 20% NO2
  - 10% N2O
  - 5% N2
  - 5% O2
  - traces of CO, CO2

My question is:

- What would be the color of the sky/of the atmosphere?

Comment: [This page](http://www.scratchapixel.com/old/lessons/3d-advanced-lessons/simulating-the-colors-of-the-sky/atmospheric-scattering/) gives a good explanation of how to compute this. I'd write something up, but the calculations are much easier to implement in C++, and are perhaps best left for a programmer.

Comment: Would the 'sky' be visible from the surface? NO2 is a brown gas - it seems like that would severely limit your visibility.

Answer (score 2):

Since NO is generally thought of as a colorless gas, it would not have a direct color, but would generate a coloration through a similar process as our atmosphere (Rayleigh scattering).  This process is based on the molecular size of the gas and is based on the wavelengths of the light (blue light has a shorter wavelength than red so is scattered less).  NO molecules are similarly sized to our atmospheres major constituent N2 and O2.  This would tend to produce a blue coloration. [This is a great simplification of the process.]

NO2 however does have a color, it is reddish brown (actually the leading contributor to smog coloration).  This would limit your visibility through the atmosphere considerably producing a much hazier atmosphere and be a major contributor to coloration.

The combination of these sources should lead to an atmosphere in the dirty purplish coloration.

**I'm assuming a light source that is colorless, a redder or bluer star would change the color of the sky accordingly.